# Find two webelements in one arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to find these two elements in the same array, however none is returned when I tried printing them out. Am I wrong in using the + operator?

```
List<WebElement> buttonelement = dr.findElements(By.className(("UFIPagerLink") + ("UFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText")));
```

Comment: Just wanna clarify, you wanna find the elements with class name `UFIPagerLink` and another one with `UFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText`? Is that right?

Comment: @J.Lucky yes, you're right.

Comment: and put them in a single `List`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's concatenating `UFIPagerLink` with `UFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText` so you're ending up with searching for elements with class `UFIPagerLinkUFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText`.

What you should do is find the elements by class separately and put them on a single `List` after.

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> pagerLinkElements = dr.findElements(By.className("UFIPagerLink"));
List<WebElement> socialElements = dr.findElements(By.className("UFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText"));        

List<WebElement> buttonelement = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
buttonelement.addAll(pagerLinkElements);
buttonelement.addAll(socialElements);
```

Comment: I tried the codes and there is this error of list is abstract cannot be instantiated for the new `List`. Attempted to change to ArrayList and it works perfectly fine, but was advised to use diamond operator instead.

Comment: @dark_space No problem! Glad to help. Happy coding!